# Looping piano song that plays at 14:50 of Episode 8 of Parasyte The Maxim

Tags: music, parasyte

In episode 8 around 14:50, there's a piano song that plays where Shinichi is talking to Shimada in their red jumpsuits on a court and Shinichi thinks Shimada is there to kill him. It's basically just a piano loop.

It also plays in another scene with Ryoko Tamiya where she is sitting down talking to someone in a different episode as well.

Does anyone know the song if you want to call it that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's just a 4-5 piano keys being played and not an actual song. Can't find it listed anywhere so I guess it's just simple BGM.